# vedic scriptures on dreams - helping make use of our time while resting

Tags: scripture, dream

**Disclaimer: I don't know if this would be the technique that one should use and if it is a technique that has been used for meditative purposes, but this is a question just out of curiosity**

Sleep is a natural required process but it's really sad that we got life and we sleep 1/3<sup>rd</sup> out of it(I mean serious). Even the scriptures say that sleep is necessary and it seems training to *unsleep*(atleast for human) isn't a good practise(Mentioned even in the Bhagwat Geeta by Lord Krishna that sleep is inevitable and necessary).

**But, there is a point where we could do both sleep and unsleep at the same time.** The idea is to remain concious during your sleep, let your body heal in this *sleep* state but put your mind concious while you control your dreams. There you can uplift yourself to any aspects and I think this could be a perfect opportunity to overcome your flaws or even a place to start your spiritual journey. Some people call this *lucid dreaming*(albeit I don't know if this is a term since it's not only being aware but also manipulating your dream at will) .

**Are there any scriptures/mentions of such spiritual techniques(or even just dreaming in general) that help you uplift yourself to spiritual awareness while dreaming by manipulating your dream?(e.g. you'd create a most silent and comfortable place where you meditate in your dream)**

Comment: what do you mean by spiritual awareness?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda , um... spiritual conciousness if you prefer, or some synonyms would be self awareness, enlightenment, etc

Comment: Probably [Yoga Nidra](https://yogainternational.com/article/view/yoga-nidra-introduction-to-the-complete-practice)

Comment: @juztcode: There was a mention about a state, in some books, in which the Yogi remains awake, apparently sleeping.  In other words, every person in the vicinity will think that the Yogi is sleeping, which includes snoring also, but in fact he is wide awake and connected to the NATURE or God.  It is very difficult to explain, but there are mentions about this state in lives of Yogis

Comment: @srimannarayanakv , the comment above mentions the state of Yoga Nidra, any scriptures you know of that describe this?

Comment: @HinduKid , any scriptures that mention Yoga Nidra?

Comment: @juztcode: Sorry I am not aware of such techniques.  Teachings of True saints, whom I follow, never lay stress on such techniques.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv , amongst Lord Shiva's 112 ways of understanding one self, could this also be a path. Do you know of any ancient ways that describe his ways?

Comment: I have little knowledge about it..Yoga Tadavali - Adya Sankaracharya mentions YogaNidra.. Look into these Links [1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281783577_Origin_and_application_of_Yoga_Nidra) [2](http://www.yogamag.net/archives/1979/ldec79/yoganidra79.shtml)

Comment: @HinduKid, Yoga Tadavali - is it a dedicated book by Adya Sankaracharya? I didn't quite find it in archieve.org

Comment: Yoga Taravali [Here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/331559934_Traditional_Wisdom_Yoga-Taravali_of_Acharya_Shankara_Translated_by_Swami_Narasimhananda)

Comment: @HinduKid , Yoga Taravali or Tadavali?

Comment: Yoga Taravali..

Answer (score 1):

The question is

> Are there any scriptures/mentions of such spiritual techniques(or even
> just dreaming in general) that help you uplift yourself to spiritual
> awareness while dreaming by manipulating your dream?

---

One of the Yogic techniques of rejuvenating oneself and elevating oneself is savAsana (***corpse pose***).  If it is combined with any type of meditative techniques, that will elevate oneself SPIRITUALLY.

[image]

---

[Shavasana](https://www.gyanunlimited.com/health/shavasana-%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%A8-pose-steps-benefits-and-precautions/11769/) benefits

> - Meditation: Shavasana is the **best yoga pose for relaxation and meditation thereby helps to rejuvenate the molecular aspects of the
>   body like cells and tissues**.
> - Calms the body: It helps to make the body and mind fresh & afresh.
> - Stress: It is one of the important yoga poses to make the body stress free.
> - Nervous system: It is extremely beneficial for nervous system.
> - Blood pressure: It is good to normalize the blood pressure, relaxes your heart and reduces the level of anxiety.
> - Memory: It increases the concentration and memory.
> - Increases energy level: The regular practice of the asana helps to increase the level of energy in the body.
> - Insomnia: The patients of insomnia should practice the asana to get relief from it.
> - Vata dosha: If somebody has imbalance of air element, he should practice the yoga pose to overcome the problem.
> - Muscles relaxation: It removes fatigue and depression, good for muscle relaxation.

---

For better results take the help of an expert in this field.